# Does redis DBSIZE use hyperloglog to approximate the actual key size?

Tags: redis

I used pipeline to insert millions of recording using LRANGE into the database, with 23620370 unique keys. I set no memory limit and noeviction strategy, and there's no error when I do the insertion, which means I have probably inserted all records.

But when I do DBSIZE, it replies me only 21933885 keys. It means 1M keys are gone.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 21933885
```

Then I used pipe to query all 23620370 keys, but none of them are fail. So it means all keys have successful replies..

Where are my 1M keys? Do redis use hyperloglog to calculate the key size?

My code are written in golang, and used the [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) to do DB operations.

------------------- EDITION -----------------------------

Code are provided as below. Hope that is not a problem of the data.

Insert records to redis:

```
client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     "localhost:6379",
    Password: "", // no password set
    DB:       0,  // use default DB
})
pipe := client.Pipeline()
defer client.Close()

for i := 0; i < NUM_FILE; i++ {
    // prepare file
    curpath = PATH + strconv.Itoa(i)
    log.Println("Loading data from", curpath)

    file, err := os.Open(curpath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // prepare for reading lines
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for j := 0; scanner.Scan(); j++ {

        curline = scanner.Text()
        itemvalues := strings.Split(curline, "\t")    // [items, value]
        itemlist := strings.Split(itemvalues[0], "-") // [item1, item2]
        item0 := itemlist[0]
        item1 := itemlist[1]
        value, _ := strconv.Atoi(itemvalues[1])

        if curitem == item0 {
            degreelist = append(degreelist, Degree{
                Item:  item1,
                Value: value,
            })
        } else {
            if curitem != "" {
                for _, v := range degreelist {
                    pipe.LPush(curitem, fmt.Sprintf("%s\t%d", v.Item, v.Value))
                }
            }
            degreelist = []Degree{Degree{
                Item:  item1,
                Value: value,
            }}
            curitem = item0
        }
    }
    pipe.Exec()
```

Query the database:

```
client := *redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     "localhost:6379",
    Password: "", // no password set
    DB:       0,  // use default DB
})
defer client.Close()

pipe := client.Pipeline()

inp_ch := make(chan string, 1000)
go load_keys(inp_ch)

i := 0
commds := []*redis.StringSliceCmd{}
for key := range inp_ch {
    i += 1
    commds = append(commds, pipe.LRange(key, 0, -1))

    if i%10000 == 0 {
        pipe.Exec()
        for _, cmd := range commds {
            result, err := cmd.Result()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            if len(result) == 0 { // if not exist in the db
                fmt.Println("result")
            }
        }
        commds = []*redis.StringSliceCmd{}
    }
}

// process the rest
pipe.Exec()
for _, cmd := range commds {
    j++
    result, err := cmd.Result()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    if len(result) == 0 {

        fmt.Printf("%s", outstring)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check with INFO (INFO KEYSPACE) command for finding the number of keys.Does it shows same as the DBSIZE?

Comment: @Praga_t Yes. Exact the same with DBSIZE.

Comment: `dbsize` replies the actual number of keys in the currently-selected database. I can't reproduce your problem in my machine. Can you show the code?

Comment: Redis doesn't use hyperloglog for counting keys. It maintains a 'used' counter, counting keys as added or removed. The result must be exact, not approx.

Comment: @linvoker Updated per your request.